# Trusty TEE deployment alongside Android OS

Tags: android

The documentation for Trusty TEE (https://source.android.com/security/trusty/) lacks details on how to deploy Trusty OS to an Android-powered device. The compilation of Trusty TEE was successful, but it is not clear what to do with it next.

As far as I understand, the end result should boot the bootloaders from ARM Trusted Firmware (https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/projects) which would set up the trusted environment as well as the non-trusted environment, and boot the Trusty OS alongside Android OS, so they both boot at the same time and work in parallel, so that the Android OS corresponds to the non-trusted execution environment, and Trusty OS represents trusted execution environment.

The device in question is ODROID C2, but I would be happy as well if I manage to run the TEE and Android OS in emulator. I've got a sucessfully built Trusty TEE, which contains LK little kernel, and a bunch of other things I am not familiar with. My question is - what do I do with it next? How to deploy it onto a device or emulator?

Comment: hi, I'm facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?